# how to find id in a table that is skipped

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Lets say I have a table which has a primary key of 1 to X. During the development of the table there are entries which have been deleted, say I deleted entry 5. And hence the table entry will be 1,2,3,4,6,7,8. Is there a query to find all id of the primary key which has been skipped?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103016/sql-query-to-get-deleted-records

Comment: One way is to join with a numbers table and find those not in the source table. You would need to know the maximum PK in your table.

Comment: @shree.pat18 yea the maximum PK as of speaking now is at 5000

Comment: May I ask why it matters, why do you care that there are 'gaps' in the ids?

Comment: Another one that thinks these numbers are sequential.. they're not. Primary key and auto_increment serve **one purpose** - to provide unique identifier for a row. They don't provide you with sequential numbers, they are not called gaps, you shouldn't reuse them because it creates performance and concurrency problems and makes your data model unstable. TL;DR - just don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/06/find-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-with-sql/), it have a solution to your problem

Quoted from the link:

```
select l.id + 1 as start
from sequence as l
  left outer join sequence as r on l.id + 1 = r.id
where r.id is null;
```

Supposing you have a table called **sequence** with primary key column **Id** starting from **1**, With values: 1,2,3,4, 6,7, 9,...

This sample code will select 5 and 8.

Comment: what is l and what is r here?

Comment: @adit, I'm sorry, edit is not saving for some reason! it keeps processing the change but I think its stuck, all the info in the link provided, easy to find, its very clear.  I will try to update the answer later to a full working example.

Comment: what is sequence here? is it the table in question

Comment: @adit, I and R are aliases for the same table `Sequence`. L is joined to R as you see in my answer

Comment: and yes, Sequence is a table

Answer (score 0):

simsim's answer will not return all missing keys if 2 keys in a sequence are missing. SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc241/1

Instead create a numbers table and join where the key is null:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers(
    Num INTEGER
)

DECLARE @id INTEGER
SELECT @id = 1
WHILE @id >=1 AND @id <= 100000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Numbers
    VALUES(@id)
    SELECT @id += 1
END

SELECT *
FROM Numbers N
LEFT JOIN your_table YT ON N.Num = YT.PrimaryKey
WHERE YT.Primary IS NULL
```