# mysql check for gaps in numeric sequence

Tags: mysql, numbers, sequence

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340793/how-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbering-in-mysql) topic very helpful in solving my issue. But I would like to find solution to another problem. If number sequence looks like this 01258, then missing gaps are 3 4 7. Perfect result, however if sequence is 258, result is same and function neglects 0 and 1. Could you please help me with changes to that function so that would check gaps starting from 0? I have no idea even what to start with. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to create user defined function to resolve tjis issue?

Comment: Well it will be row with ids, I need sequence because everything in my site is done with JavaScript. I can't use Ajax much to check which numbers are free which are not, because Ajax is a bit slow to respond. Since everything done with dhtml I can't use submission as well. That's why I need to rearrange ids in one shot after some of lines were deleted gaps ruin my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputs a list of missing ranges as in the link provided, but within the specified range (not extensively tested).

You'll need to iterator through them to get the actual values.

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable AS ...

DECLARE @StartID INT ...
DECLARE @EndID INT ...

SELECT @StartID as gap_starts_at, 
       COALESCE((SELECT MIN(t3.id) -1 FROM tempTable t3
                 WHERE t3.id > @StartID AND t3.id < @EndID), @EndID) as gap_ends_at
FROM tempTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.id FROM tempTable t2 WHERE t2.id = @StartID)
UNION
SELECT (t1.id + 1) as gap_starts_at, 
       COALESCE((SELECT MIN(t3.id) -1 FROM tempTable t3 WHERE t3.id > t1.id),
                @EndID) as gap_ends_at
FROM #tempTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.id FROM tempTable t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1)
      AND id < @EndID
```

**EDIT:** [Here's](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/06/find-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-with-sql/) a link with a few ways to find missing values (I don't think any of them work with ranges though, but some may be easier to extend then others.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I've came to a solution =)