# django tacking back model id?

Tags: python, django

I have the following list of ids

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

If I delete id 2 and then I insert a new value, it takes id 5. 
Is it possible to re-assign automatically id 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key of a model in Django is generally represented by an auto-incrementing field which is handled by the database layer.  eg In MySQL, the [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) option will be added to the primary key.

This provides an efficient way for the database layer to assign a unique id to each record.  Without significant change to Django it won't be possible to have it *not* use an AUTO_INCREMENT type.

Instead, you will probably need to add a field which is under your control which you ensure manually does not contain any gaps.
    from django.db import models

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

It would then be up to you to assign a value to `my_id` before saving that represented your sequence which doesn't include gaps.  Finding what the next `my_id` should be on insert is probably not trivial and may not be easy to do efficiently through the Django ORM.  See [How to find gaps in sequential numbering in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4340793/302243) for some ideas.

Renumbering the original id may prove problematic, especially for any data that was created that referenced the original id.