# How to find missing IDs in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sequence, counter

I have a table where I have a row `id` that is my primary key. It is a table with ~250 thousand rows. Usually, the `id` should be a sequential number. Now I want to find out, if there is a number missing in the sequence of numbers.

Example: The table contains the `id`s

```
1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

That means, in the sequence of numbers from `1` to `10`, the numbers `3` and `5` are missing.

How would a MySQL query look like that only returns the missing `id`s? Is there a way to increment a counter and compare if that `id` exists?

Comment: Sure, just compare `COUNT(*)` with `MAX(id)`; that's assuming you don't have master-master replication.

Comment: @juergend This table is kind of an OLAP table. So I want to know the missing `id`s to check if all "parent items" are being analyzed.

Comment: @Jack Doesn't return the missing `id`s, but I like this approach. Nice and easy!

Comment: So you rely on an auto_increment to provide referential integrity while not actually using foreign keys and you rely on the notion that auto_increment is sequential (hint: it's purpose is not to be sequential). tl;dr - your architecture is, by definition, wrong.

Comment: @N.B. You're right: My question does not make sense because the original items are not sequential (because items may have been deleted in that original sequence). Thanks for that hint. I was already wondering why `COUNT(*) <> MAX(id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Linux script populate a table `test(id:auto-increment)` up to your max value of `your_table`. Then execute something like

```
select id from test where id not in (select id from your_table)
```

The output will be the missing.

Comment: Yeah, this helps. Unfortunately it is not dynamically; I have to update this help table each time my original table changes.

Comment: I am not sure for this statement: Select id+1 from your_table Where not EXISTS (select distinct id from your_table)

Comment: Also this post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340793/how-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbering-in-mysql