# Group consecutively values in MySQL and add an id to such groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database, gaps-and-islands

I have a simple table and I need to identified groups of four rows (the groups aren't consecutives), but each rows of each row has a +1 in the value. For example:

```
----------------------
| language     | id  |
----------------------
| C            |  16 |
| C++          |  17 |
| Java         |  18 |
| Python       |  19 |
| HTML         |  65 |
| JavaScript   |  66 |
| PHP          |  67 |
| Perl         |  68 |
----------------------
```

I want to add a column that indicates the group or set, how is possible to get this output using MySQL?:

```
----------------------------
| language     | id  | set |
----------------------------
| C            |  16 |  1  |
| C++          |  17 |  1  |
| Java         |  18 |  1  |
| Python       |  19 |  1  |
| HTML         |  65 |  2  |
| JavaScript   |  66 |  2  |
| PHP          |  67 |  2  |
| Perl         |  68 |  2  |
----------------------------
```

Note that in this examples is only 2 sets (it could be 1 or more sets) and they didn't start in 16 (such values are not knowledged, but the restriction is that each id value of each row has this form n, n+1, n+2 and n+3).

I've been investigating about **Gaps & Islands problem** but didn't figure how to solve it by using their solutions. Also I search on stackoverflow but the closest question that I found was [How to find gaps in sequential numbering in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340793/how-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbering-in-mysql)

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to perform this query on an ongoing basis, or is this a one-time query that you are going to use to populate `set` values?

Comment: This query should be used multiple times with dynamic data (the values of the groups of 4 rows can change but such groups aren't cosnecutively, i.e. there aren't 2 groups that cover from 1 to 8 id values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select language, 
       @n:=if(@m+1=id, @n, @n+1) `set`, 
       (@m:=id) id 
   from t1, 
        (select @n:=0) n, 
        (select @m:=0) m
```

[**Demo on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99105d/1)

Comment: Without ORDER BY the results are not guaranteed

Comment: from the question condition i don't see, whether next group will  not start from 1 :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT language,id,g
FROM (
  SELECT language,id,
    CASE WHEN id=@lastid+1 THEN @n ELSE @n:=@n+1 END AS g,
    @lastid := id As b
  FROM
    t, (SELECT @n:=0) r
  ORDER BY
    id
) s
```

EDIT

In case you want just 4 per group add a row number variable:

```
SELECT language,id,g,rn
FROM (
  SELECT language,id,
    CASE WHEN id=@lastid+1 THEN @n ELSE @n:=@n+1 END AS g,
   @rn := IF(@lastid+1 = id, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
    @lastid := id As dt
  FROM
    t, (SELECT @n:=0) r
  ORDER BY
    id
) s
Where rn <=4
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36738/2)

Comment: How does this query identify groups of *4* consecutive records?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos The same it identifies 3 or 2 or 10 consecutive records.It checks it the the next record has the id +1 of the previous one.

Comment: I think the OP wants *only* groups of *4* consecutive records returned and everything else filtered out.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I think that is just the sample data,but it that is the case its easy to fix with a row number per group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT l.*, s.rn
FROM languages AS l
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT minID, @rn2:=@rn2+1 AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS minID
    FROM (
      SELECT id,
             id - IF (true, @rn1:=@rn1+1, 0) AS grp
      FROM languages
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1:=0) AS var1 
      ORDER BY id) t    
    GROUP BY grp
    HAVING COUNT(grp) = 4 ) u
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2:=0) AS var2  
) s ON l.id BETWEEN minID AND minID + 3
```

The above query identifies islands of *exactly 4* consecutive records and returns there records only. It is easily modifiable to account for a different number of consecutive records.

Please also note the usage of `IF` conditional: it guarantees that `@rn1` is *first* initialized and *then* used in order to calculate `grp` field.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4b15/3)

Comment: If I insert more values only returns the 1 and 3 id's: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4b15/1/0

Comment: @Wronski My solution is filtering out any islands of records whose population is different than *4*. I thought this was the requirement of the OP.