# mySQL grouping by sequential records and assigning ID to groupings

Tags: mysql

I have the following [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c1866).

This is a very similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814492/group-consecutively-values-in-mysql-and-add-an-id-to-such-groups), but I want to expand a bit more on what the original question is asking. I am fairly new to mySQL, so I've never really dealt with anything like this before.

I need to identify the records in which there are at least 3 consecutive semesters having:

> units_enrolled = 0

I then need to assign an ID to the sequential groupings, but the ID must reset upon a new stdnt_id.

Lastly, I want to also indicate whether or not the student enrolls at some point after a pause.

Something like these results:
[Result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXpik.png)

Would this even be feasible in mySQL and on a large-scale basis?

Comment: show your sample data ang expected result

Comment: This question needs improving because either I interpret the question literally, then it is a yes / no question, or I interpret is as a code request (there is no own effort demonstrated), then I would have deem it as too broad.

Comment: Btw, it is feasible in mysql, whether it is efficient on a large scale that's up to you to test.