# How get items which all not present in mysql Table in a range

Tags: mysql

I have an mysql table where Ids are between 1 to 1815. but some of the Ids are not available. For example 15, 22, 55 etc..

How to get those ids??

I tried

```
select product_id from table_products where product_id not BETWEEN 1 and 1815
```

But its not working.

Comment: What do you mean "not available"? There's no record on product_id = 15?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find gaps in sequential numbering in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340793/how-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbering-in-mysql)

Comment: yes...There is no record on product_id =15

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't exists in table then you can hard code the values using `UNION` like below. Well, I had no idea about [How to find gaps in sequential numbering in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340793/how-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbering-in-mysql). Which looks really nice and probably a much better solution than what I am proposing.

```
select product_id 
from table_products 
where product_id BETWEEN 1 and 1815

UNION

select 15 as product_id from dual

UNION

select 22 as product_id from dual

UNION

select 55 as product_id from dual
```

Comment: Hard coding? I just need those ids? you mean to say i manually scan table and find all the ids and then union them?

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal, Yes you got it else see another post link in answer for finding gaps. Cause, those values doesn't exists in table and so you will have generate them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer in [How to find gaps in sequential numbering in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340793/how-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbering-in-mysql][1]) and found it really does the trick (adapted for your purpose):

```
    SELECT
 CONCAT(z.expected, IF(z.got-1>z.expected, CONCAT(' thru ',z.got-1), '')) AS missing
FROM (
      SELECT
      @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS expected,
      IF(@rownum=table_products.product_id, 0, @rownum:=table_products.product_id) AS got
     FROM
      (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS a
      JOIN table_products
      ORDER BY table_products.product_id
     ) AS z
    WHERE z.got!=0;
```

Hope this does the job for you. The only thing it does not do is stop at a particular product_id, but I assume you can look at the result and take the data that you need.