# MYSQL: Find missing values in a sequence by different groups

Tags: mysql

Hy, little help please, I have a full sequence of 12 items, I identify these items by 2 different groups (12345 and 54321). Now, I need to identify the first sequence of the item "12345" stop at 4 and restart at 10. Something like that:

I have this table:

```
------------------
|seq  |partNumber|
------------------
| 1   |  12345   |
| 2   |  12345   |
| 3   |  12345   |
| 4   |  12345   |
| 10  |  12345   |
| 11  |  12345   |
| 12  |  12345   |
| 5   |  54321   |
| 6   |  54321   |
| 7   |  54321   |
| 8   |  54321   |
| 9   |  54321   |
------------------
```

I need to find this result:

```
------------
|Start|Stop|
------------
|  5  |  9 | (partnumber:12345)
------------
```

the query that I used:

```
select start, stop from (
 select m.partNumber + 1 as start,
    (select min(partNumber) - 1 from seq as x where x.partNumber > m.partNumber) as stop
  from seq as m
    left outer join seq as r on m.partNumber = r.partNumber - 1 where r.partNumber is null) as x
where stop is not null;
```

But, this query gives me this result:

```
------------
|Start|Stop|
------------
|  9  |  9 | (partnumber:12345)
------------
```

Final result:
I want to identify sequence of "12345" starts in 1 ends in 4 (break) restart at 10 ends 12, I have a gap in 5 to 9. The other sequence of "54321" starts at 5 ends in 9, here I don't have a gap.

Comment: beat me to it, @User42

Comment: Can you, in this application, assign an upper bound to the value of `seq`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find gaps in sequential numbering in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340793/how-to-find-gaps-in-sequential-numbering-in-mysql)

Comment: Its the same result. So it doesn't work for me, I already tested. Thanks nada

Comment: @Ollie Jones, can you be more precise?

Comment: What is the largest value of `seq` your application will ever encounter?

Comment: @OllieJones probably fit's in 0000 to 9999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good application for the *structured* part of *structured query language.*

I guess you will never have a value of `seq` less than zero or greater than the arbitary value `15624`. That guess is important: we need a table of all the cardinal numbers in that range to get missing-number detection to work.

Here is such a table

```
SELECT A.N + 5*(B.N + 5*(C.N + 5*(D.N + 5*(E.N + 5*(F.N))))) AS seq
  FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS A
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS B
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS C
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS D
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS E
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS F
```

(If you're using MariaDB, you can use the [Sequence](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/) table `seq_0_to_15624` in place of this lump of SQL code.)

Next, you need a way to find out the lowest and highest value of `seq` for each part number.  You do that like so.

```
       SELECT partNumber, MIN(seq) minSeq, MAX(seq) maxSeq
         FROM seq
        GROUP BY partNumber
```

Next, you need to generate a table showing all the possible sequence numbers from minimum to maximum for each part number:

```
SELECT cardinals.seq, r.partNumber
  FROM (
        SELECT A.N + 5*(B.N + 5*(C.N + 5*(D.N + 5*(E.N + 5*(F.N))))) AS seq  
          FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS A
          JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS B
         JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS C
         JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS D
         JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS E
         JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS F
       ) cardinals
  JOIN (
         SELECT partNumber, MIN(seq) minSeq, MAX(seq) maxSeq
           FROM seq
          GROUP BY partNumber
   ) r ON cardinals.seq >= r.minSeq AND cardinals.seq <= r.maxSeq
```

Finally, you can LEFT JOIN that to your original table and do `WHERE val IS NULL` to locate your missing sequence numbers.

```
SELECT cardinals.seq, r.partNumber
  FROM (
        SELECT A.N + 5*(B.N + 5*(C.N + 5*(D.N + 5*(E.N + 5*(F.N))))) AS seq  
          FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS A
          JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS B
         JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS C
         JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS D
         JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS E
         JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS F
           ) cardinals
  JOIN (
             SELECT partNumber, MIN(seq) minSeq, MAX(seq) maxSeq
               FROM seq
              GROUP BY partNumber
       ) r ON cardinals.seq >= r.minSeq AND cardinals.seq <= r.maxSeq
  LEFT JOIN seq ON cardinals.seq = seq.seq AND r.PartNumber = seq.partNumber
 WHERE seq.seq IS NULL
```

Comment: Ok, that works. Thanks Ollie, but can we group them like:
Start - 5 ;
Stop - 9? I'll try

Comment: Find it: SELECT min(cardinals.seq) as START, SELECT max(cardinals.seq) as STOP, r.partNumber (...)

Once more, Thanks Ollie, save my day.

Comment: Hi, Ollie Jones, the query generate an **NULL**: I've sequence 7298 up to 7478 of one part number but in the middle I've other part number(the sequence of this part number is 7375 to 7434) and this query don't find this gap. Supposedly the result would be 7298 - 7374(one part number); 7375 - 7434 (the other part number) and finally 7435 - 7478(the first part number again). can you help me?